# Using and meaning of "social responsibilities"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Can I use a phrase "social responsibilities" talking about things I have to do with social meaning?
e.g. " I have some social responsibilities today so I will be back late." Taking about a few business meetings with clients or taking friends for coffee.

Comment: It refers to [responsibility to society at large](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_responsibility), so it sounds ostentatious in that context.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! ... You ask a good question, although it is probably best to ask it on the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site. If you agree, you can move it over there. But if you want to wait to see what a moderator says, that's fine too. :o)

Comment: "Social commitments" would be a better expression.